# HTML5 Camera on Chrome not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser

I am trying to view the Camera for the user on Chrome but it has stopped working in recent months. It used to work a few months back but now it doesn't work.

```
// Get access to the camera!
    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
            //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); Firefox gives error on this line now but didn't used to it
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        });
    }
```

How can I get camera working on Chrome using html5?

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/vjukm5fb/11/)**

Comment: Here is a working fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/0mgok0Ln/

Comment: @Alicia doesn't work for me on chrome

Comment: Okay, then there's something up with your browser, as for me, both examples work fine

Comment: @Alicia do you have the latest Chrome version. This used to work in the older versions

Comment: Yup, running Chromium 74, on Arch. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: I'm running Chrome 79 and above Fiddle is still broken.  Also tested Uppy.io examples they are broken too, must be Chrome which sucks big time!